# Playing video with html5 in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, meanjs

When i used code:

```
    <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640" height="264">
      <source src="http://localhost:3000/files/public/photos/Let-her-go.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
      <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
```

It operates normally, no problem

But, when i used

```
    <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls width="640" height="264">
        <source src="{{ video.url }}" type='video/mp4' /></source>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
```

I have defined

```
.filter('trusted', function($sce) {
  return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
})
```

Video don't play, but i check firebug, video.url has a value availble

How can help me fix it, sorry, my English is bad

Answer (score 0):

Change your source line to:

```
<source ng-src="{{ video.url }}" type='video/mp4' /></source>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, when i chekc firebug it like:  `<source type="video/mp4" ng-src="http://localhost:3000/files/public/photos/Let-her-go.mp4" src="http://localhost:3000/files/public/photos/Let-her-go.mp4"></source>`

Comment: I did the exact thing and it works for me, where are you using the filter "trusted". Also can you post your controller code here